# Integration of AWS billing invoices in Azure cost management

Tags: aws-billing, aws-organizations, azure-billing

We have integrated AWS Billing invoices in Azure cost management such that in azure cost management, we can see the costs of all the AWS accounts we have in the root account along with Azure billing. Now we're removing our root account and every OU's we have in that root account is now associating with another root account. The new root account already has multiple OU inside which we have nothing to do with it.

My question is how can I set up the AWS Billing integration with Azure that takes AWS billing invoice of specific OU and send them over to Azure. as far as my understanding we can only set up integration with an AWS Root account or with an individual account, it doesn't operate on an OU level. I want this because I am only responsible to check billing invoices for my OU only or else it will show us the whole OU's billing we have in that root account and it will become much messier to track the cost down of my OU.

I don't find any documentation on this. so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that but your concern is to track bill across your AWS services and accounts you can use some external tools like CloudSpend